# How can I integrate My bot from AWS Lex in my Laravel App or test it using Postman?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, postman, amazon-lex

I have created a bot using AWS Lex. Now I want to integrate it in my Laravel App. But I'm not able to find the end point what do I need. Before doing it in Laravel I am testing it on Postman.

I tried following: [Test an Amazon Lex Chatbot using a REST client (Postman) | by Andy O'Sullivan | Dev Tutorials](https://tutorials.botsfloor.com/test-an-amazon-lex-chatbot-using-a-rest-client-postman-c2d9ce81dcad)

However, it doesn't help. Still struggling but not getting expected response

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS-SDK it will help to integrate in to your Laravel app.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/lex_code_examples.html